# Как убрать border?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать квадратный border от preview?

```css
.add-photo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 0px;
}

#preview {
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 00%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

input[type='file'] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-photo">
  <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();">
    <img id="preview">
  </form>
</div>
```

решение --> нужно в src добавить "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs="

Comment: В src прописать корректную ссылку на картинку, border сам исчезнет

Comment: на прозрачную картинку

Comment: Если разобрались, добавьте ответом. "Решено" в заголовок не нужно добавлять.